# Append a string to a static final String declared in an abstract class

Tags: java

I have the following abstract class

```
public abstract class IStreamSorterTest<T> {

    protected static  String FOLDER_NAME = null;
    protected static  String FILE_EXT = null;
    protected static  String SCHEMA_FILE_EXT = null;
    protected static final String PATH_PREFIX = "src/test/resources/" + FOLDER_NAME;
    protected static final String USERS_FILE = "users" + FILE_EXT;
    protected static final String SORTED_USERS_FILE = "sorted_users" + FILE_EXT;
    protected static final String USERS_XML_SCHEMA = "users_schema" + SCHEMA_FILE_EXT;
```

Extended by several classes in which I would like to ONLY define the variables FOLDER_NAME, FILE_EXT and SCHEMA_FILE_EXT without creating new variables.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: This is not possible in Java, there is no concept of overwriting a static variable. Use a getter instead.

Comment: A getter in the abstract class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make these variables `static` as they would only exist in the superclass.

You could pass these Strings to the abstract class' constructor:

```
public abstract class IStreamSorterTest<T> {

    protected final String pathPrefix;
    protected final String userFile;
    protected final String sortedUserFile;
    protected final String usersXMLSchema;

    protected IStreamSorterTest(String folderName, String fileExt, String schemaFileExt) {
        pathPrefix = "src/test/resources/" + folderName;
        userFile = "users" + fileExt;
        sortedUserFile = "sorted_users" + fileExt;
        usersXMLSchema = "users_schema" + schemaFileExt;
    }

}
```

Then in a subclass:

```
public class SomeClass extends IStreamSorterTest<SomeType> {

    private static final String FOLDER_NAME = ...;
    private static final String FILE_EXT = ...;
    private static final String SCHEMA_FILE_EXT = ...;

    public SomeClass() {
        super(FOLDER_NAME, FILE_EXT, SCHEMA_FILE_EXT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!